# Mysql strange behaviour on querying tinyint boolean field

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table `voucher_codes` with the following schema:

```
mysql> describe  voucher_codes;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id            | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| promo_code         | varchar(30)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| voucher_value      | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created       | datetime(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_modified      | datetime(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| redeem_flag        | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fk_voucher_rule_id | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The indexes defined on the table are as follows:

```
mysql> show index  from voucher_codes;
+---------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| voucher_codes |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id                 | A         |    15280692 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| voucher_codes |          1 | voucher_codes_user_id    |            1 | user_id            | A         |     2805369 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| voucher_codes |          1 | voucher_codes_promo_code |            1 | promo_code         | A         |     7389780 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| voucher_codes |          1 | fk_voucher_rule_id       |            1 | fk_voucher_rule_id | A         |          60 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The numbers of records with voucher_code 1 and redeem_flag as 0 and 1 are as follows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =0 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   135114 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.17 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =1 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1575024 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.56 sec)
```

There are 1.5+ million records with `redeem_flag` as `1` and 100k+ are `0`.

But the query with `redeem_flag` as `1` takes less time as compared with query with `redeem_flag` 0.
Below are the results:

```
mysql> select promo_code from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =0 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1  limit 1 ;
+--------------+
| promo_code   |
+--------------+
| XXXXXXXXXX   |
+--------------+
1 row in set (3.67 sec)

mysql> explain select promo_code from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =0 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1  limit 1 ;
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | voucher_codes | NULL       | ref  | fk_voucher_rule_id | fk_voucher_rule_id | 4       | const | 3258352 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Query with `redeem_flag` as 1:

```
mysql> select promo_code from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =1 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1  limit 1 ;
+------------+
| promo_code |
+------------+
| XXXXXXXXX  |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select promo_code from voucher_codes  where redeem_flag =1 and fk_voucher_rule_id=1  limit 1 ;
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | voucher_codes | NULL       | ref  | fk_voucher_rule_id | fk_voucher_rule_id | 4       | const | 3258352 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Unable to understand this behaviour. Even though the index `fk_voucher_rule_id` is getting used, but it is taking more time with records which are more as compared to less number of records.

Update: Adding show create table result:

```
mysql> show create table voucher_codes;
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| voucher_codes | CREATE TABLE `voucher_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `voucher_value` double NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `redeem_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fk_voucher_rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `voucher_codes_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `voucher_codes_promo_code` (`promo_code`),
  KEY `fk_voucher_rule_id` (`fk_voucher_rule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16305657 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your `redeem_flag` field does not seem to be indexed. Yes, you are using `fk_voucher_rule` but that still returns 3.2 million rows which then need to be checked for `redeem_flag`. Add a composite index on two columns `redeem_flag, fk_voucher_rule` and rerun your query

Comment: But it is a boolean field with values only 0 or 1. Do we need to index that ?

Comment: Also, if it is not indexed, why is the redeem_flag = 1 returning results so quickly ?

Comment: It's not boolean field, int's tinyint field which you perceive as boolean. Index it.

Comment: using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is always meaningless as SQL tables/resultset are always orderless..

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and add that output as those `DESCRIBE table` and `SHOW INDEX.. ` outputs are it bit harder to read, they do add nice infromation to know like cardinality which is nice to know also, `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` is nice and clean, also makes testing alot more easy..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Using order by `fk_voucher_rule_id` or `id` is also giving the same results. Also have updated the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results

Comment: Also, to test the speed of a query use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` instead of `SELECT ...` to disable caching. Query that executes in 0.00 is most likely cached

Comment: .. speaking of Cardinality, the index Cardinality (60) of fk_voucher_rule_id seams way to low that MySQL should choose for index lookups this seams a bit odd.. also a key like `(fk_voucher_rule_id, redeem_flag)` would/should give better performance but be sure to remove `KEY fk_voucher_rule_id(fk_voucher_rule_id)` first otherwise the optimize might mix up the indexes, i seen it happen before when having redundant indexs/keys..

Comment: I tried SQL_NO_CACHE and it executes in 0 seconds only

Comment: Using composite index worked. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @roushankumar if you are satisfied with an answer, consider accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, test speed of your queries using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` instead of just `SELECT ...`. It is quite odd that query runs in 0.00 time.

Furthermore, create a composite index on `redeem_flag, fk_voucher_rule` and then retest your queries for comparison.

NOTE: You should use same order of fields in a query as it is in your index. Also, as @Raymod Nijland said, remove redundant indices. For example, if you have index `fk_voucher_rule, redeem_flag` it will be used both for queries that use only `fk_voucher_rule` and `fk_voucher_rule, redeem_flag` queries (other way around does not apply, you can't use it only for querying `redeem_flag`).

Comment: @RaymondNijland for ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland for mentioning redundant indices? Sure. Added.

Comment: *"for ? "* just messing around ... *"NOTE: You should use same order of fields in a query as it is in your index"* is not true ... index `(fk_voucher_rule_id, redeem_flag)` can be used for `WHERE fk_voucher_rule_id = ? AND redeem_flag = ?` or `WHERE redeem_flag  = ? AND fk_voucher_rule_id = ?` order does not matter..  See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xeZqVmPyY7kgeJ7ux12oWD/0)

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah, but it's neater to use the same order, and avoids confusion (at least for me), hence `you should` and not `you must`

Comment: Well really you should use `index(fk_voucher_rule_id, redeem_flag)` if you would use `index(redeem_flag, fk_voucher_rule_id)` and `WHERE redeem_flag = ? AND fk_voucher_rule_id = ? ` MySQL has more scanning to do (FULL table scan most likely) as `redeem_flag` has less unique values i assume only 0 and 1 -> *"redeem_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL"* ..